# Updating JS Array in angular $scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to update array inside $scope. For eaxample

```
$scope.data = [{detail:{name: "...", cred:"...."}, date:"current date"},...];
$scope.update = function(){
  $scope.data[0].date = "new date";
}
```

But the value is not updating. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post more of what you're trying to do? There is no array here.

Comment: edited code in the question.

Comment: Still not clear how you invoking `update` function and how you detect that update not applied. Show usage of `$scope.data` in view and where from `$scope.update` called

Comment: $scope.data = [{detail:{name: "...", cred:"...."}, date:"current date"},...];
$scope.update = function(){
  $scope.data[0].date = "new date";
  console.log($scope.data[0].date); //this prints current date not new date
}

Comment: @Praishgm where from the `$scope.update` invoked?

Comment: It's updated by ng-click. The function gets call. Everything else works as expected. The object inside array is not updating.

Comment: Check you code for typos. If won't find any it's better to illistrate you case on Plunker

Comment: won't get much help without more code shown and/or a demo that replicates it

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.data = [{detail:{name: "...", cred:"...."}, date:"current date"},...];
$scope.update = function(){
  $scope.data[0].date = "new date";
}
```

Hi, at times the above angular view may not reflect the changes directly, so to achieve this, use $watch or $watchCollection;

```
$scope.$watchCollection('data', function(value){
  $scope.data = value;
});
```